# Alternative for Webpack Dev Server for Single Page Applications in production

Tags: javascript, web-server, http

Webpack Dev Server is for serving a Webpack app at `https://localhost`. The issue I'm having is that I want to both develop Single Page Applications and publish them to the public (that is, production).

The [Webpack Dev Server's repository](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) says:

> Use webpack with a development server that provides live reloading. This should be used for **development only**.

I need a HTTP server for publishing to the public (production), specially for Single Page Applicaitons (which redirect inexistent URLs to other existing URLs or create URLs dynamically to allow search engine integration). Any alternatives to Webpack Dev Server?

I'm aware of httpd and nginx, but I want to know if there are any easier to use. About Express, I never heard of it being used for client view; has it ever been used for? And if there are more complex layers over Express, that would help too.

Also, my endgoal is to currently create a Single Page Application framework by internally using such HTTP server.